Percentage of total by category of smaller subset
I have a list of people and some of them may fit into category A, B, or C, or not have a category. What I need to show is the percentage of each category against the whole list. For example I have a list of 100 people. 20 in CatA, 15 in CatB and 15 In CatC. The other 50 people have no category.
In a separate Pie Chart thing, I already show the split of those with a category, so Cat A is 40% and B and C as 30% each
What I need to do is have those percentages as a percentage of the whole 100, instead of just the 50 with a category, so the Cat A would show as 20% and B and C as 15% each.
At the moment I have the Category as legend, and the People being counted as values. However, that excludes people who don't have a category from the calculation.

you can try to create a new column
Category2 = if('Table'[Category]="","no category",'Table'[Category])


Then add the new category in the legend

